# Do I need to escape every string and what is the maximum length of an escaped string?

Tags: php, string, salt, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to store a randomly generated salt in my database with SQL. I have generated this salt in php using this line of code:

```
$salt = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, mcrypt_create_iv(256, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

As I understand it all strings must be escaped regardless of whether they are derived from user input as my random salt could also have special characters which interfere with SQL regardless of whether they are intentionally malicious? As I also understand to escape the string PHP needs to add extra characters thereby increasing the length of the string. I was wondering what the maximum length of the string would be post-escaping? Is it that only one character is added for each infringing character in the string therefore the maximum length of the string is 512 for my 256 character string?

Thanks

Comment: Don't escape. Use bind parameters instead.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: @JayBlanchard to hash a password with a salt you need to be able to store the salt. As far as I can ascertain the only way to store a salt with the inbuilt PHP functions is to generate your own which is what I am doing here. Also I am using hash_pbkdf2 function which is much more secure than the PHP hashing function because you can perform any number of iterations. Surely using the PHP functions is sub-par?

Comment: No, that would not be correct. The password hashing function provided by PHP generates a random salt for each hash *which is much more secure*. You can modify the cost (iterations) by adding options to the function. Keep in mind that you'll want to find the ideal costs for your system, but typically the default works more than very well without additional computations needed by your server.

Comment: But then would I not need to store the salt? I cant see any way of that function outputting the salt without generating and storing it myself? Thanks

Comment: You do not need the salt, all you need to do is verify the password when a user logs in using PHP's [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). That way you're performing one-way password hashing which is the most secure way of storing passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't escape. Use [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead.

That aside, the size that counts is the unescaped value. Escaping is only to make it safe for the parser to read the string. The actual string value is still the same size (and will be handled in unescaped form by the MySQL engine). Escaping is just a way to safely embed a value in the query.